# How to pass values from a dynamic list from one page to another in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm working with PhoneGap I have created a SQLite database that stores the name  and a unique number along with an autoincrementing p_id field. I am using jQuery Mobile to fetch the result and display it in a listview, here is the code

```
function Patientquery(tx)
{
tx.executeSql('SELECT P_ID, P_UNIQUE_NO, P_FIRST_NAME, P_LAST_NAME FROM Triage where P_ID > 6',[],query,errorCB);  
}

function query(tx,result)
{
 $('#Patientlist').empty();
 $.each(result.rows,function(index){
 var row = result.rows.item(index);
 $('#Patientlist').append('<li><a href="#"  data-role="button" id='+row['P_ID']+'><img src="male.gif" /> <h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+row['P_FIRST_NAME']+'</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">'+row['P_LAST_NAME']+' '+row['P_ID']+'  </p></a></li>');
   });
        $('#Patientlist').listview();


        $('#Patientlist li').on("vclick",function(){
       alert("Selected"); // sample alert
       localStorage.currentId = $('a',this).attr("id");
       $.mobile.changePage($("#Page1"));
    });
```

My problem is i was not able to use `$('#Patientlist li').on("vclick",function()`. My requirement is to select a listed value and send the p_id as a parameter to the next page.